# Mint Cannot login, because wrong keyboard layout in /etc/default/keyborad

Tags: authentication, layout, keyboard, linux-mint, keyboard-layout

I setted wrong keyborad layout in /etc/default/keyborad and now cannot login, there is russian alphabet and I cant enter my password in it. Unfortunately its same in ctrl+alt+F1 text console.. I tried external live usb disk and decrypted my disk there, but I was not allow to edit file from there, just to read it. Can I login as root or user from the live usb and edit the file. Or fix it somehow? Or clear reinstall is needed?

I set cs instead of cz..

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. During the Linux Mint installation, I accidentally selected the wrong keyboard layout. Later I fixed it by removing the old one and adding the proper keyboard, but unfortunately, this had no impact on the login screen.

Solution:

1. login and show your current, working layout configuration with `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`
2. check the layout that is used on the login screen: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`
3. set up properly the login screen keyboard layout with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

That was the only solution that worked for me.
I hope that it helps you as well.